# Create Customize Sliding tabs

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am new to android development. In my project I want to create a sliding tabs.I did some research on sliding tabs but not clear on how to customize it. My tabs will look like this:

[image]

So please can you help me out on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried so far, it would be very helpful for everyone!

Comment: Sir i have'nt started any thing bcos i dont know how to customize it as i want the shown in the link

Comment: If there are only three tabs, than you can use buttons instead of tabView.

Comment: Yes there will be only three tabs

Comment: Everyone is new at some stage! there are plenty of resources available on the web, try to search and try to implement first yourself, post it here again if you face any issue in the implementation!

Answer (score 1):

First you will need the "logic" of the SlidingTabLayout. You can take it from the official documentation, also I will put it here. This class must be used inside a ViewPager.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


/**
 * To be used with ViewPager to provide a tab indicator component which give constant feedback as to
 * the user's scroll progress.
 * <p>
 * To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your
 * {@link android.app.Activity} or {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} call
 * {@link #setViewPager(ViewPager)} providing it the ViewPager this layout is being used for.
 * <p>
 * The colors can be customized in two ways. The first and simplest is to provide an array of colors
 * via {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and {@link #setDividerColors(int...)}. The
 * alternative is via the {@link TabColorizer} interface which provides you complete control over
 * which color is used for any individual position.
 * <p>
 * The views used as tabs can be customized by calling {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)},
 * providing the layout ID of your custom layout.
 */
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

/**
 * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
 * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
 */
public interface TabColorizer {

    /**
     * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
     */
    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    /**
     * @return return the color of the divider drawn to the right of {@code position}.
     */
    int getDividerColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Disable the Scroll Bar
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

/**
 * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
 *
 * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
 * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and {@link #setDividerColors(int...)} to achieve
 * similar effects.
 */
public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
 * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for tab dividers. These colors are treated as a circular array.
 * Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setDividerColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
 * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
 * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
 *
 * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
 */
public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
 *
 * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
 * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
 */
public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}

/**
 * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
 * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
 */
public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

/**
 * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
 * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
 */
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
        // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
    }

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 35);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                    positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

After that you will need another class that will define how it looks its UI. This one it's the class that you must modify to change the style.

```
/**
    * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
    *
    * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    * You may obtain a copy of the License at
    *
    *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    *
    * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    * limitations under the License.
    */



class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 2;
private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 8;
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

private static final int DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 1;
private static final byte DEFAULT_DIVIDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x20;
private static final float DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT = 0.5f;

private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

private final Paint mDividerPaint;
private final float mDividerHeight;

private int mSelectedPosition;
private float mSelectionOffset;

private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
    final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

    mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

    mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setDividerColors(setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_DIVIDER_COLOR_ALPHA));

    mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

    mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();

    mDividerHeight = DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT;
    mDividerPaint = new Paint();
    mDividerPaint.setStrokeWidth((int) (DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density));
}

void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
    mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
    invalidate();
}

void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
    mCustomTabColorizer = null;
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
    invalidate();
}

void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
    // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
    mCustomTabColorizer = null;
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setDividerColors(colors);
    invalidate();
}

void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final int dividerHeightPx = (int) (Math.min(Math.max(0f, mDividerHeight), 1f) * height);
    final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
            ? mCustomTabColorizer
            : mDefaultTabColorizer;

    // Thick colored underline below the current selection
    if (childCount > 0) {
        View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
        int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
        int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
        int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

        if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
            int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            if (color != nextColor) {
                color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
            }

            // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
            View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
            right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
        }

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }

    // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
    canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);

    // Vertical separators between the titles
    int separatorTop = (height - dividerHeightPx) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        mDividerPaint.setColor(tabColorizer.getDividerColor(i));
        canvas.drawLine(child.getRight(), separatorTop, child.getRight(),
                separatorTop + dividerHeightPx, mDividerPaint);
    }
}

/**
 * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
 */
private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
    return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
}

/**
 * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
 *
 * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
 *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
 */
private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
    float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
    float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}

private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
    private int[] mIndicatorColors;
    private int[] mDividerColors;

    @Override
    public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
    }

    @Override
    public final int getDividerColor(int position) {
        return mDividerColors[position % mDividerColors.length];
    }

    void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mIndicatorColors = colors;
    }

    void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
        mDividerColors = colors;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think that the optimal way is the pure Android. Here you can take the code paste it and you only "need to change" the UI. I think that It shoudln't be so difficult....

Comment: @ascostela Thanks sir for you time but sir i am not getting it how will i make it look as the way in the link?

Comment: It's only a guide yo must change the values in the class SlidingTabStrip to modify the style according to what you need. If you read these classes carefully you will see that commented code will help you a lot. Inside the comments you will find where you must modify your code